# Entity Framework Code First and CA2227 "Collection Properties should be read only"

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-analysis

A one-many or many-many relationship in Entity Framework Code First looks like this:-

```
public class Foo
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

This violates Code Analysis rule 2227 "Collection Properties should be read only".

Making the setter protected doesn't help, and making it private:-

```
public class Foo
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; private set; }
}
```

then of course violates CA1811 "Foo.Bars.set(ICollection<Bar>) appears to have no upstream public or protected callers".

I'd rather not turn the rule off globally because the situation it exists to prevent is fairly important, but suppressing it locally every time I want to declare a relationship seems off. Is there a way to declare the relationship that doesn't violate CA2227?

Comment: I was having the exact same problem. After I didn't find any reasonable solutions, I decided that SuppressMessage() is maybe the most pragmatic way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place all your code first entities in their own assembly and exclude the rule for that assembly.

Answer (score 14):

Change your code to the following:

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo() {
        Bars = new Collection<Bar>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the benefit?

Comment: A writable collection property allows a user to replace the collection with a completely different collection. A read-only property stops the collection from being replaced, but still allows the individual members to be set. If replacing the collection is a goal, the preferred design pattern is to include a method to remove all the elements from the collection, and a method to repopulate the collection. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2227

Comment: I disagree, the preferred design pattern is applicable only to Java where there are no setters and getters and you have to write them yourself for each property. Setters/Getters in C# where specifically created to avoid writing this redundant code for each property. That is especially true in classes that are 1:1 mapping with DB models, there is absolutely no reason to wrap them up in methods.

Comment: You are disagreeing with Microsoft then as it is their view and their static code analysis rule.